# Why is density functional theory unreliable for prediction of band gap

Tags: solid-state-physics, electronic-band-theory, density-functional-theory

Why is density functional theory unreliable for calculation of band gap?

Comment: Maybe the question is supposed to start with "Why"? In any case please add some context

Comment: Is it? Historically, DFT has had problems, particularly with narrow gap materials. Not surprisingly, people have worked hard to improve the functionals and understand where some of the algorithm/numerical problems are and how to avoid them. But, this is kind of like asking why RK methods are better then direct forward integration to solve many differential equations.

Comment: This has been answered [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/360454/226809).